# Sub setting the dataframe and renaming based on the value of subset

Tags: python, pandas, list, subset

I have a dataframe which looks like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Fruits':['Apple','Avacado','Banana','Bluberry'],'Alphabet':['A','A','B','B']})
```

I want to subset this data frame based on the alphabet and name the subsets with the corresponding alphabet

The straight forward way of doing this is

```
A = df.loc[df['Alphabet'] == 'A']
B = df.loc[df['Alphabet'] == 'B']
```

But I would like to automate it, if in case I have all the 26 alphabets in the dataframe.

I tried putting the unique values of alphabets in to a list

```
alphabets = list(df['Alphabet'].unique())
```

And then created a list of individual dataframes

```
dfs = []
for letters in alphabets:
    df = df.loc[df['Alphabet']==letters]
    dfs.append(df)
```

Is it possible to assign the item names of the list alphabets to dataframe items of list dfs

Comment: I suggest create dictionary  by this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45400233/2901002)

Comment: @jezrael yes its an elegant solution and I have tried that in a different way too, but how to rename that dictionary key name to 'a' (corresponding alphabet) and store it as a data frame?

Comment: It is not necessary, because for keys in dictioanry ket alphabets and for values get DataFrames.

Comment: But it is possible, by [globals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45567689/2901002)

Comment: Yeah , I get that. But ultimately I want to store the subsets as dataframe

Comment: @jezrael Thank You , I was looking for this globals()