# Create of multiple subsets from existing pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df` as:

```
date       coun tk  so
2017-07-05  1.0  24  1
2017-09-04  1.0  24  2
2017-08-10  1.0  24  3
2017-10-30  1.0  24  4
2017-07-15  1.0  4   1
2017-07-31  1.0  4   1
2017-08-17  1.0  4   2
2017-05-02  1.0  4   1
2018-01-01  49.0 14  1
2017-11-27  49.0 24  1
2017-09-27  49.0 14  1
2017-10-20  49.0 24  1
2017-09-20  49.0 14  1
...
```

All I want to create subsets datasets from existing dataframe `df` for each pairs?
So, all I want something like,

`df1`

```
date       coun tk  so
2017-07-05  1.0  24  1
2017-09-04  1.0  24  2
2017-08-10  1.0  24  3
2017-10-30  1.0  24  4
```

`df2`

```
date       coun tk  so
2017-07-15  1.0  4   1
2017-07-31  1.0  4   1
2017-08-17  1.0  4   2
2017-05-02  1.0  4   1
```

`df3`

```
date       coun tk  so
2018-01-01  49.0 14  1
2017-09-27  49.0 14  1
2017-09-20  49.0 14  1
```

`df4`

```
2017-11-27  49.0 24  1
2017-10-20  49.0 24  1
```

There are many other possible pairs existed in dataframe `df`.

Comment: I suggest use `dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby(['coun', 'tk'])))`

Comment: @jezrael Thanks sir. How I can seperate dictionary keys, values pairs into individual dataset

Comment: Possible, but not recommended - `for i, (v, df) in enumerate(df.groupby(['coun', 'tk'])):
     globals()['df' + str(i)] = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Changed solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45567689/2901002)